# pdf report creation using pdfkit python django

Tags: django-4.0, python-pdfkit, django-wkhtmltopdf

I am creating pdf report using pdfkit 0.6.1 and  from_url method in django 4 python
but the problem on my local system pdf is creating as I required but when i am pushing code on production server it is creating pdf like this:
[pdf content is not showing proper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6t5m.png)
i have tried so many times but the problem is same..
`your text`

## production server wkhtmltopdf installation snap-

[production server wkhtmltopdf installation snap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DerSm.png)

all the code running on local but not on production server...

any body give me solution if you have i have been trying for 2 months..

Comment: IMHO, your production server compresses its responses via methods like gzip, so you have to decode it.